# Jquery cannot append to a ordered list with HTML as content

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I am trying to append to an ordered list based on the JSON response i receive from the server. The response contains HTML tags and for some reason they are not getting rendered in HTML.I did a console.log for the response message and it appears to be fine. However when i append this to my list it does not show on screen.

I am using ajax call with jquery and PHP/Mysql in the backend.

here is jquery code snippet:

```
 success: function (response) {
                    var responsedata = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    console.log(responsedata.msg);
                    $('#step3ul2').append("<li>"+responsedata.msg+"</li>");
                    $("#finalmsgsuccessdiv").show();    
                    },
```

The console.log prints:

```
<a href = '../editrequest/index.php?q=88>Request id 88</a> was successfully added in the system
```

however the browser shows nothing.

Comment: Are you sure your selectors are correct? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Obvious, but just incase, do you have an element with id `step3ul2` and `finalmsgsuccessdiv` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be that the href attribute on the 'a' tag doesn't have the single quote closed?

```
<a href = '../editrequest/index.php?q=88>
```

vs

```
<a href = '../editrequest/index.php?q=88'>
```

Comment: yup it seems that the ' was causing the issue....i guess its time to go home..too late :) Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: hehe, yeah, sometimes the answer lays in our dreams (or lack of it). Good luck!

Comment: seriously man i was thinking may be something is wrong with jquery parsing json...or a bug in my php sending back data etc etc went all the wrong way digging into stuff that made no sense :):) I am a 1 man army building the whole app on my own and don't have a team per se to work with...however i was wrong....i have a huge team and its called the stackoverflow team!!! :):)